# Divergence Theorem for any measure in $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: integration, analysis

It is well known that 
$$
\int_{\Omega}div(f)\,d\lambda\;=\;\int_{\partial \Omega} f.\nu\,\ ds
$$

is true where $d\lambda $ is lebesgue measure and $ds$ is surface measure for $\mathbb R^n$.

Is the result true when $d\lambda$ is any other measure than Lebesgue measure?
(notice that the corresponding surface measure will change if we change measure)

Comment: What exactly is the relation between $d\lambda$ (or any other measure) and the "corresponding" surface measure?

Comment: I am also not so clear, but I know is if the measure comes from a function, the surface measure should be restriction of that function. But I dont know what it is otherwise, it is an open question.